# Search and delete some lines in ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I am copying a file from share and i am trying to search a line of code and after that remove some line of code & then save the file again with same name.

suppose I have the below content in myconfig.ps1 file

```
WriteHost("My operations");
WriteHost("My Object Creation");
$mytmp.NewObjectCreation($myobj1);
$mytmp2.NewObjectCreation($myobj2);
WriteHost("My Object Creationcompleted");
WriteHost("My operations completed");
```

The output file  should be the same name as original file i,e, myconfig.ps1 and content as below

```
WriteHost("My operations");
WriteHost("My Object Creation");
WriteHost("My Object Creationcompleted");
WriteHost("My operations completed");
```

I have tried below for one statement, its not working:

```
$s1 = [regex]::escape("$mytmp.NewObjectCreation($myobj1);")
$c1 = [regex]::escape("#$mytmp.NewObjectCreation($myobj1);")


Get-Content $originalbuildspecfile | ForEach-Object {
    $_ - $s1, $c1 
    } | Set-Content ($originalbuildspecfile )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get-content` to read the content of the file, pipe each line to `where-object` with some condition and save it again using `set-content`.
In case you want to write to the same file you are reading from, you will have to save the content in a variable, otherwise you will get an error saying that the file is already being used.

For example:

```
PS> $file = "c:\temp\myconfig.ps1"
PS> $content = get-content $file | where {-not $_.StartsWith('$') }
PS> set-content $file -Value $content
```

This example will check each line in 'myconfig.ps1' and will put in the variable `$content` only the lines that do not start with '$'.
The third line will take the value stored in `$content` and will put it into 'myconfig.ps1'.

Note that if your source file location is different from the destination file location, you can do that in one single line, like so:

```
PS> get-content "c:\temp\myconfig.ps1" | where {-not $_.StartsWith('$') } | set-content "c:\other_location\myconfig.ps1"
```

Hope this helps.